# measurable function and composition of function

Tags: real-analysis, probability, measure-theory

Show that if $f$ is a measurable function and $g$ is a continuous function on $\Bbb R$
then $g\circ f$ is measurable.

please tell me how to prove it !

Answer (score 1):

Hint: a function is Lebesgue measurable if the inverse image of every open set is Lebesgue measurable.

Comment: If E is measurable set and f is continuous on E, then f(E) is measurable set.   is it true ?

Comment: No.  Counter examples are tricky though.  I'd try looking in your book for that.  There is counterexample one using a variant on the Cantor function.